# How to automaticlly place the emacs window on the right of the screen at start with GNOME?

Tags: emacs, gnome

I want the Emacs window to be at the right of the screen at start up. I have search a lot and I am close to find but I can't exactly force the window to take exactly the half of the screen, like when you take the windows with the mouse and drop it to the right of the screen.
I can place the window at the right place, set the right size, but it left some tiny pixels that i can't fill.The window is not exactly the same form and do not fill the same pixels.

Thank you for help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Emacs Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html):

> **User Option: frame-resize-pixelwise**
>
> If this option is nil, a frame’s size is usually rounded to a multiple of the current values of that frame’s frame-char-height and frame-char-width whenever the frame is resized. If this is non-nil, no rounding occurs, hence frame sizes can increase/decrease by one pixel.

Your problem should be solved by adding `(setq frame-resize-pixelwise t)` to your settings.